# Jade - print all possible variables

Tags: node.js, pug

I would like to be able to display all available variables that the currently loaded jade file has access to.

I realise this is a little odd, but there you go :)

I am not really bothered if its in the console or outputting to the page.

```
console.info(res.locals) //this gives back way more than jade has access to.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign that `locals` onto a property of itself

```
app.use(function locals(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.locals = res.locals;    
    next();
});
```

Then simply access `locals` in your Jade template.