# How can I point facebook meta tag og:url to a relative link two levels up?

Tags: pug, mean-stack, facebook-opengraph, relative-path, meta

I need to point my og:url tag to a longer-lived page two levels up.  I am writing my views in a jade/pug template.

The tag for the page in question should be:

```
meta(property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/cat/tabby/tagNumber/59c27/../..")
```

which is equivalent to

```
meta(property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/cat/tabby")
```

But my pages are dynamic, and I do not know the best way to specify the url.
I really want to be able to do something neat like:

```
meta(property="og:url" content="./../..")
```

But that is wrong according to the OG spec, and ignored by the facebook crawler.

Is there a way to do something more like this:

```
meta(property="og:url" content= thisVarURL +"/../..")
```

Without modifying my controller functions to send a url variable to my view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an automated way of doing this, but you can certainly pass an environment variable `thisVarURL` to each view, and assign it the URL value. If you want a more elegant way of doing it, I suggest combining the middleware approach outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267805/jade-print-all-possible-variables) with the retrieving of a request's URL through the snippet given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183291/how-to-get-the-full-url-in-express).

No idea if this works, but it could look something like this:

```
app.use(function locals(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.thisVarURL = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
    next();
});
```